# Swift, in the GCD, SIGUSR1 does not work

Tags: swift, signals, grand-central-dispatch

Following it tried formed a code, but the trigger of SIGUSR1 does not work.
Will what is not enough?

```
signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
let que = dispatch_queue_create("Que", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
let source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_SIGNAL, UInt(SIGUSR1), 0, que)

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, {
    NSLog("BLOCK doing")
})

dispatch_resume(source)

sigaction(SIGUSR1, nil, nil)
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: On the playground, even if does not output.

Comment: Try it in a compiled project.

Answer (score 1):

### Resources for research "Signal handling in Swift":

1. [Kernel Architecture Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Architecture/Architecture.html)
2. [iOS Developer Library: signal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html)
3. [iOS Developer Library: sigaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sigaction.2.html)
4. [Github IBM-Swift/BlueSignals/.../Sources/Signals.swift](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSignals/blob/master/Sources/Signals.swift)

### Code (create Command Line Tool project)

```
import Foundation

var signalSource: dispatch_source_t!
var signalOnceToken = dispatch_once_t()
let signalID:Int32 = SIGUSR1

func initSignalHandler(signal: Int32) {
    dispatch_once(&signalOnceToken) {

    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
        signalSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_SIGNAL,
                                               UInt(signal), 0, queue)
        if let source = signalSource {
            dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source) {
                NSLog("signal: \(signal)")
            }
            dispatch_resume(source)
        }
    }
}

initSignalHandler(signalID)

sleep(1)

// send signal
Darwin.raise(signalID)

NSLog("End")
```

### Result images

[image]
[image]